# Accessing folder out of root directory public_html

Tags: hosting, cpanel

My friend gives me his cpanel access, his site was developed by other developer. I can't understand one thing in there. Please help me to understand it.

As I know, a hosting can be attached with only one domain, and the website files-and folders should be in the root directory (public_html folder). But somehow this hosting is connected with two domains and both is working!. Suppose the main domain is abc.com and it is attached with the hosting, which files are in the root directory (public_html).

Also another domain (def.com) attached with this hosting but it's files are not in the root directory (public_html).

So how do two domains pointing to one hosting? How come the files which is not inside the root directory(public_html) still pointing the other domain(def.com) and working perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be they have added second domain as an addon domain in same cPanel account. You can check addon domain list through cPanel >> Domains >> Addon domain and check the addon domains document root path.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a multi domain hosting where you can host multiple websites. One domain would remain Main and the other domains can be attached under Add on Domains. It works exactly same as Main domain however the website would be in sub-directory of main root. You can check the number of add on domains under cpanel > Domain Manager > domain list.